# Sci-fi film set in 1960s USA with aliens; ends with John F. Kennedy's assassination

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I saw this film about 20 years ago. It takes place in the USA during the Cuban crisis. A CIA agent investigates alien sightings. At one point in the film, the agent and his cohorts go take a look at some crop circles or such, being guided by a farmer. Then the farmer goes bonkers and a car chase ensues. Afterward, the farmer is on an autopsy table and doctors discover he has some parasite in his head.

Another fragment of the film I remember is of a monkey in a lab, that perhaps has the same alien parasite embedded within it, escapes its cage and later shoots one of the guards with a gun. In another scene, the main protagonist's girlfriend has one of the alien parasites within her, and she has to drink some milky substance to get rid of it.

Later in the film, the main protagonist argues that all the info about the aliens should be disclosed to the President. His superior disagrees, so the agent sneaks into the President's house and plants an alien artifact where the President can see it, then flees with his girlfriend. Later in some motel, they find out the President (J.F.K.) has been assassinated.

Comment: John F. Kennedy, assassinated? What crazy alternate history is this?!?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might be referring to *[The Awakening](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0554697/)*, the pilot episode of the short-lived '90s TV series, *[Dark Skies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Skies)*.

[image]

> The series presents the idea that 20th century history as people know it is a lie. It depicts aliens having been among humans since the late 1940s, with a government cover-up concealing their existence from the public. As the series progresses, viewers follow John Loengard and Kim Sayers through the 1960s as they attempt to foil the plots of the alien "Hive". **The Hive is an alien race that planned to invade Earth through a manipulation of historical events and famous figures, including most notably the assassination of President John F. Kennedy**.

> **The series depicts The Hive as an alien species who are covertly invading Earth. They are a parasitic race of small multi-legged spider-like beings that can take control of host bodies, by attaching themselves to the brain**. They do this by entering through orifices on the head, commonly the mouth, though they are also shown to enter by squeezing through the nose and ears, with great discomfort to the host. Due to the way they attach themselves to the brain's ganglion regions, the series' protagonists dub the creatures "Ganglions".

Definitely matches some of the plot points you mentioned, like the agent (pictured above) investigating crop circles near a farm, the homicidal farmer with the parasite in his head (which reanimates his corpse while the autopsy is being performed), and a reveal of John F. Kennedy's assassination at the end.

Comment: At first glance, that picture looked like a promo shot for the *X-Files*.  I imagine that was intentional on their part, as the show was pretty clearly influenced by it.

Comment: That trailer sounds like parody, lol. Also, that trailier looks like an entire episode.